# Есть ли в php возможность указания нескольких возвращаемых типов?

Tags: php

Есть ли в php возможность указания нескольких возвращаемых типов?

К примеру у меня есть метод в котором в зависимости от условия отправляется либо int либо string. Использую версию 7.2

```
public function getSomething(): int <-- речь идёт об этом
```

Comment: Функция/метод должна возвращать что-то одно. Если это не так - значит в архитектуре/логике что-то не то и надо исправлять именно логику.

Comment: Вроде как в PHP нету строгой типизации, и случаев когда функция возвращает, например, либо int, либо string - довольно много. Вы можете возвращать либо строку либо просто число, а затем проверять это значение при помощи, например, isNumeric. Другой вопрос - насколько это правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. С одной стороны, можно возвращать и строку и число (потому как число тоже может быть строкой), с другой стороны если вы возвращаете либо число, либо объект, либо массив объектов - это уже странно и вызывает вопросы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с версии 8.0 в РНР появилась возможность указывать несколько типов. Однако этой возможностью следует пользоваться очень аккуратно.

В частности, в вашем случае, когда функция может вернуть либо int, либо string.

Если вам это надо, то вы не понимаете строгую типизацию, и используете её механически, как карго культ. Весь смысл строгой типизации в том, что аргумент или возвращаемое значение имеет один, строго определенный тип.

Плюс, скорее всего такая функция нарушает принцип единственной ответственности, делает слишком много. И её надо разбить на функции помельче.

Если же вы всё равно хотите писать по-старике, когда функция может возвращать что угодно, просто не указывайте тип.

Но правильнее будет, как отметил Сергей Мишин в комментарии, переписать функцию так, чтобы она возвращала значение только одного типа.

Как вариант, функция может выбросить исключение или вернуть null. В последнем случае перед типом можно поставить знак вопроса, `?int`.

Comment: Подобные штуки вполне можно описать одним строго возвращемым типом наподобие `Union[int, str]` или `enum Something { Foo(i32), Bar(String) }` (в зависимости от конкретного языка)

Answer (score 1):

Такого не предусмотрено к сожалению [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.returning-values.php). Есть возможность обнуления типа, добавляя знак вопроса перед типом данных `?int`

Comment: Не "к сожалению", а совершенно правильно. Какой смысл вообще вводить типизацию, если снова делать шалтай-болтай?

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно реализовать с помощью [PHPDoc](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html):

```php
/**
 * @return integer|string
 */
public function getSomething()
{
    //..
}
```

Но как и сказали комментаторы выше, в самом PHP задать несколько типов нельзя, т.к. это неправильно с точки зрения строгой типизации.

Answer (score -2):

в PHP 8.0 появились перечисляемые типы через знак |, и более того - есть тип mixed - любое значение. Т.е. теперь если нужно то пишем int|float, и это нормально.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin в каком месте это комментарий?

Comment: @Ипатьев примерно в том, которое вы удалили.

Comment: В вопросе у автора не  int|float, а int|string. И с вероятностью 99% это не модная, стильная, молодёжная фича, а старый добрый пахучий говнокод

Comment: Ну так теперь как мнение экспертов выглядит не красиво, так и мой коммент подтереть можно.... Зачем такое делать?. Спасибо что вернули.

Comment: Писать надо по делу, а не выплескивать эмоции. Тогда не попадёшь по гильотину :)

Comment: Вполне по делу. Так как коммент описывает, что спешка и горячка не нужна, тем более когда это выплескивают эксперты. И что теперь делать людям ,которые вместо одной функции понаписали кругом по 2-3-4 с одним и тем же по сути функционалом? Это же был явный вредный совет изначально. Смысл комментария в этом. Не нужно спешить.

Comment: Я именно это и написал в своём ответе, "Если вы хотите писать по-старике, когда функция может возвращать что угодно, просто не указывайте тип." Что не так?

Comment: Просто совет переписать кучу отдельных функций только из за типа мне кажется был вредным. А вот совет не писать тип - это на тот момент был реально выход ,которого и нужно было строго держаться. Я надеюсь мы понимаем друг друга и обиды не будет.